# How does Aloe Vera leave a cool feeling on your skin? Why does it evaporate fast?

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry

If you have ever grown Aloe Vera and applied it to your skin, it feels a bit slimy. However, after it evaporates it has a cool feeling on your skin.

Also, why does the Aloe Vera evaporate so fast? What is it made of, apart from water that makes Aloe Vera do this?

---

I am assuming Hand Sanitizer and Aloe Vera are not directly connected.

Answer (score 3):

The leaf of aloe vera is composed of three layers: 1) An inner clear gel that contains 99% water and rest is made of glucomannans, amino acids, lipids, sterols and vitamins. 2) The middle layer of latex which is the bitter yellow sap and contains anthraquinones and glycosides. 3) The outer thick layer of 15–20 cells called as rind which has protective function and synthesizes carbohydrates and proteins. So overally , it consists of about 99% water and remaining are vitamins, enzymes, minerals, sugars, lignin, saponins,etc.

So what makes inner layer gelly ?? Well, the innermost part of the leaf is a clear, soft, moist and slippery tissue that consists of large thin-walled parenchyma cells in which water is held in the form of a viscous mucilage consiting of cellulose, hemicellulos and acetylated mannans.

As for you question, as most of it consists of water(99%) the cool feeling might has been felt due to its evaporation but some of its remaining constituents are absorbed in the skin. Mucopolysaccharides present in it help in binding moisture into the skin.Its one of the important medical applications is that it could potentially be used as a
penetration enhancement agent for the transdermal delivery of drugs and intestinal absorption of coadministerd drug <sup>[1](https://www.mdpi.com/1420-3049/13/8/1599)</sup>.

Saponins that are the soapy substances are found in the gel of aloe vera and have cleansing and antiseptic properties <sup>[2](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2763764/)</sup> so you can say that hand sanitizer and aloe vera are somewhat connected.

**References**

1. Hamman, J.H. Composition and Applications of Aloe vera Leaf Gel. *Molecules* **2008**, *13*, 1599-1616. https://doi.org/10.3390/molecules13081599
2. Surjushe, A., Vasani, R., and Saple, D. G. Aloe vera: a short review. *Indian J Dermatol.* **2008**, *53*(4): 163–166. doi: 10.4103/0019-5154.44785

Comment: I always assumed that the primary effect was not evaporation but something like the action of menthol which directly affects the temperature sensing nerves to create the illusion of coldness.

Comment: I had that assumption too initially but I couldn't find any of it's  chemical constituents like that of menthol. So I stated that evaporation "might" solve the mystery to some extent. Likewise some of its constituent are absorbed but I am not sure they would play any role.

Comment: So,your edit to the answer with authentic logic is highly appreciated.

Comment: So, you are saying its just mostly evaporation?

Comment: It might be one of the logical options(considering that 99% is of water). We can feel considerable extent of cooling effect due to evaporation of water that we have practically observed as well.